# Separating Words by Syllable Count

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting, twitter

I'm trying to write a twitter bot that replies to people with a random haiku, but I'm having trouble creating the structure for it in javascript. In the code I've attached you'll see that using p5.js I've loaded two text files, one with a bunch of nouns and the other with a bunch of adjectives. I then split them by syllable using some code I found, but I can't figure out how to re-organize my list into separate arrays per syllable amount.

like "oneSyllable = []", "twoSyllable = []" etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated- even just an explanation of what the regex function does would help. This one- (/(?=[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '')

Also, is there an easier way to do this within javascript? Using p5 means I'll have to run it to the twitter bot using the command line, something which I still have to learn. If you have any additional information on making a haiku twitter bot please let me know! I've done a bunch of research but I can't find any source code for the several that are out there.

This is for a code final due soon and I'm way out of my depth!! Hope someone can help.

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(600, 6000);
fill(0);

loadStrings("./nouns.txt", doText);
loadStrings("./adjectives.txt", doText2);
}

function doText(data) {
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
text("Nouns list:", 5, 20);
text(data[i]+ ": " + (new_count(data[i])), 5, 20*i+50);
}
}

function doText2(data) {
for (var j=0; j<data.length; j++) {
text("Adjectives list:", 100, 20);
text(data[j]+ ": " + (new_count(data[j])), 100, 20*j+50);
}
}

function new_count(word) {
word = word.toLowerCase();
if(word.length <= 3) { return 1; }
word = word.replace(/(?=[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');
word = word.replace(/^y/, '');
return word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store words organized by syllable count in a dictionary with keys being syllable count and values being lists of words having the respective syllable count.

Provided any object in JavaScript is an associative array, which is just another term for "dictionary", you may end up with the following function to re-organize your lists:

```js
function groupBySyllableCount(wordList) {
  var wordsBySyllableCount = {};
  for (var i = 0, len = wordList.length; i < len; i++) {
    var slblCount = new_count(wordList[i]);
    if (wordsBySyllableCount[slblCount] === undefined) {
      wordsBySyllableCount[slblCount] = [wordList[i]];
    } else {
      wordsBySyllableCount[slblCount].push(wordList[i]);
    }
  }
  return wordsBySyllableCount;
}


// TEST & DEMO:

var nouns = ['air', 'time', 'community', 'year', 'people', 'woman', 'house', 'research'];
var nounsBySyllableCount = groupBySyllableCount(nouns);
console.log(nounsBySyllableCount);

function new_count(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  if(word.length <= 3) { return 1; }
  word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');
  word = word.replace(/^y/, '');
  return word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length;
}
```

As of the `(?=[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$` regex, it matches

- either `es` not preceded by `l`, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, or `y`,
- or `ed`
- or `e` not preceded by `l`, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, or `y`

but only if they are go just before end of string (a word in your case), which is denoted by the `$` anchor. The `(?=...)` is a positive look-ahead and used here merely to group the `[^laeiouy]es`, `ed` and `[^laeiouy]e` patterns to state that each of them should be followed by end of string.

In fact using a positive look-ahead is an overkill here. Grouping with a capturing (`(...)`) or a non-capturing (`(?:...)`) group construct would be enough. See the amended regex in my demo above.